# How do I mirror a card or the word in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with this CSS, when I hover to see the details of the movie it flip but the whole word in it flip too.
Is there a way that I can make the word flip first and then when I hover the word becomes normal?

This is the HTML code, it was written in JS file and the CSS code.

```css
body {
  background-color: var(--primary-color);
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.overview {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(101%);
}

.movie:hover .overview {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<img href = "#" src =https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/7b/a5/a47ba59b4a353e0928ef0551ca44f980.jpg>
<div class="movie-info">
    <h3>Title</h3>
</div>
<div class="overview">
    <h3>Overview</h3>
        lorem ipsuim
    <br/>
</div>
```

[image: card flip gone wrong]

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card {
  position: reletive;
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

.card__side--back {
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
/*   background-color: orange; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: orange;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.card__side--front {
  height: 400px;
  width: 250px;
/*   background-color: orange; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: teal;
}

.card:hover .card__side--front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

.card:hover .card__side--back {
  transform: rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="card"> 
  <div class="card__side"> 
  <div class="card__side--front">This is the front </div>
    <div class="card__side--back"> This is the back</div>
</div>
</div>
```

From my understanding this is what you were trying do achieve. The key here is backface-visibility and hovering on the container that contains both cards, because when hidden it cant be hovered over.